# CakePHP: efficiently loading a static left menu

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I'm setting up a few CakePHP template files (.ctp) for a controller `test`. I have `/test/index` and `test/search` pages, which uses `index.ctp` and `search.ctp`, respectively.

There's a left-hand size vertical menu section that goes into each of these pages, but it seems redundant and unnecessary to include the same HTML code in every `.ctp` files that will go under `/test/`.

The code for this left menu is something like below, and I'd like to avoid copying and pasting it every time I create a new page. Is there a way to load a separate file that includes this code for all `.ctp` files for the `test` controller? Or maybe I'm approaching this the improper way? I'm learning off of the default template file that came with CakePHP 1.3 right now.

```
<div class="actions">
    <h3><?php __('Menu'); ?></h3>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Product Search', true), array('action' => 'search')); ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also, while I have this question up, what is the significance of class name ("actions") in the `div` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the HTML in an [element](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1081/Elements) to easily reuse it. Put the HTML you want to reuse in a file located at: `app/views/elements/some_element.ctp`. Call it what you want.

Then add this to your view or layout files:

`echo $this->element('some_element');`

`actions` is just a class. The only significance is what you give it in your css.

Using the default Cake CSS and layout, `actions` is a div that floats left, allowing easy access to links generated by `baking`.

Comment: you nailed both of my questions. Thank you so much!